# $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p+\sqrt{p}})$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q} \iff p=n^2+1$ for a prime $p$.

Tags: galois-theory

Recently, I have encountered a question saying that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p+\sqrt{p}})$ is not always Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$, with the counterexample $p=3$.

My professor then followed up with that question and said that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p+\sqrt{p}})$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $p$ is a prime of the form $n^2+1$.

So far, I have managed to prove the $\Leftarrow$ direction, but got stuck trying to prove the other.

I considered the polynomial $h(x)=x^4-2px^2+p^2-p$, and noted that it is both a separable and irreducible polynomial. Since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p+\sqrt{p}})$ is a Galois extension, the roots of $h(x)$, that is, $\pm\sqrt{p+\sqrt{p}}, \pm\sqrt{p-\sqrt{p}}$ all lie in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p+\sqrt{p}})$.

I have also shown that $\sqrt{p-1}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p+\sqrt{p}})$, and then I'm stuck.

So my question is, how do I proceed from here?

Comment: I don't really get how you showed the $\Leftarrow$ direction. I think you are either skipping a lot of steps, or actually missing something crucial here.

Comment: @DonThousand I used the same $h(x)$ as above and showed that its splitting field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p+\sqrt{p}},\sqrt{p-\sqrt{p}})$ is equal to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p+\sqrt{p}})$. Since $h(x)$ splits on the LHS, it also splits on the RHS, and hence RHS is Galois. Is my approach incorrect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $p$ is prime. The Galois closure of $L=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{p+\sqrt p})$
is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{p+\sqrt p},\sqrt{p-\sqrt p})$. So $L$ is Galois
over $\Bbb Q$ iff $p-\sqrt p$ is a square in $L$.

By Kummer theory, $p-\sqrt p$ is a square in $L$ iff either it
is a square in $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt p)$ or if $(p+\sqrt p)(p-\sqrt p)$
is a square in $K$. In the former case $N(p-\sqrt p)=p^2-p$
must be a square in $\Bbb Q$, which it isn't as it's a multiple
of $p$ but not of $p^2$. In the latter case $(p+\sqrt p)(p-\sqrt p)=p(p-1)$
is a square in $K$. The rationals that are squares in $K$ are the
squares of rationals or $p$ times the squares of rationals. $p(p-1)$
is not a square of a rational, and is $p$ times a square of a rational
iff $p-1=n^2$ where $n$ is an integer.

Comment: I have not seen Kummer theory mentioned in the course, so I'm having a hard time trying to follow the answer. Is there another answer that does not rely on it?

Comment: What text are you using? D&F has a short introduction to it.

Comment: @DonThousand My course is using both Cox's and Rotman's Galois Theory.

Comment: Both definitely introduce Kummer Theory.

Comment: @DonThousand Alright I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @piixy3 You don't need the full force of Kummer theory here, just the fact that the elements in a field $F$ which are squares in $F(\sqrt a)$ are the squares in $F$ and $a$ times the squares in $F$. That said, Kummer theory is well-worth learning.

Answer (score 1):

One can directly apply the criterion which appears in the question of @user289143, with $K=\mathbf Q$ and $L=\mathbf Q(p+\sqrt p)=\mathbf Q(\sqrt p)$. Then $L(\sqrt {p+\sqrt p})$ is galois over $\mathbf Q$ iff $(p-\sqrt p)/(p+\sqrt p)$, or equivalently $(p-\sqrt p)(p+\sqrt p)=p^2-p=p(p-1)$, is a square in $L$. But $p-1$ is a square in $L$ iff it is of the form $a^2+pb^2+2ab\sqrt 2$, with $a,b \in \mathbf Q$. The only possibility is $b=0$, from which we derive easily that $p-1$ is the square of an integer.